# Use grunt to include sources into html in particular order (for AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am trying to use Grunt for my AngularJS project. Including bower-components is no problem with [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) (previously grunt-bower-install). But I want also to automatically include all the scripts I have made. I am following the new file structure that the [Angular team proposes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub). There is a Grunt plugin, [grunt-include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source), but I have no success using that, since I need for some of the files to be in a particular order. I need my app.js to be on the top and I need a component module definition file to be before the other files of that component...

Any ideas on how to automate this?

Edit: Just to mention, I make this work by a ugly hack. Grunt-include-source can order by directory (parent first) and ascending for files within a folder. So in my root app folder, I have app.js and app-controller.js, so there I rename app.js so that it comes first, and since "+" is before "-", I rename it to app+.js. And similar for other files that need special ordering... But I do obviously not want to continue to use this hack.